# Invisible device and ADB driver

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to my Prestigo PMP3370B using ADB. But the device is not listed in my W7 64bit connected hardware list (only as USB disc). I already checked on device option in developer option on phone. I'm also not mouting it as USB disc.
There is also no specific ADB driver (or I can't find it) to this type of device, but I want at least try to use some generic driver pro this device. Does someone known what is the best approach to do that? How to make the device visible?
Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that command `adb.exe devices` doesn't list your device? (You only mention OS point of view)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I already installed ADB drivers for most manufacturers (phones) before, but I have problem with this new device.

Comment: Have you installed some kind of driver from Prestigo?

Comment: There are only drivers for firmware flash when the device is off-line.

Comment: Try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11874830/322939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted my local Prestigio user support which told me to use default ADB drivers, but it didn't work. They didn't send me any special driver or didn't know about any.
Then I contacted international user support which told me that they didn't provide this ADB driver to users/developers.
I returned this tablet to the seller. The end.