# Issue with tablet detection Synchro Digital

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, detection, tablet

My colleague and I have to develop and implement an application on an Android tablet for a company. We started and almost completed the development of the application in question using the Eclipse AVD (we hadn't recieved the tablet yet) and it works perfectly.

We received the tablet on which the application must be installed, the model:
SynchroDigital INOSOP10-4.0 RES, 10" with ICS, less than 100 €, the really cheap one.

Our problem: my PC doesn't recognize the tablet (WIN7, unable to install drivers when connecting, although I've already successfully developed on Galaxy S and Galaxy Tab). I have access to the storage space when I activate mass storage but it is not recognized as a tablet, therefore it can't compile directly from Eclipse, nothing appears in the device list.

Enabling USB debugging doesn't change anything.
No activity in the logcat when connecting the tablet.
In device management, I find the tablet under Other Devices / Android, with the yellow triangle. The manufacturer's website offers a "Support" section, but no link to the drivers.
Tried with another PC, same result.

Any ideas? Is it possible that some tablets doesn't allow developing directly from Eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, this is a driver problem.  Unfortunately you are rather out of luck without the driver.

There are a couple things you can try from easiest to hardest:

1. If you have a MAC in the office, try it, you often don't need a driver.
2. If the device is rooted, you can use ADB wirelessly
3. You can try modifying the google android driver (see below)

**EDIT** This method works reliably on Windows.  If you are running Windows 8, you have to reboot into the advanced startup menu and disable driver signing to install the modified driver.

Google includes the USB drivers for the Nexus devices as part of the SDK.  If you haven't installed the Google USB Driver package from the SDK Manager, do so.

From the SDK folder, I see the drivers here:
/android-sdk-windows/google-usb-driver/

Opening the android_winusb.inf, you can see a sample entry for the Nexus One:

```
;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01
```

**NOTE** This entry is in two locations (the 32-bit driver and 64-bit driver sections).  We are going to create a new entry, but ours will most likely only have 2 hardware IDs.  So under the [Google.NTx86] section, create an entry:

```
;SynchroDigital INOSOP10-4.0 RES
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, 
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install,
```

Now we need to fill in the blanks.

- Open up device manager
- Go to Other Devices / Android and open up the entry with the yellow
  triangle
- Go to details tab
- Select hardware IDs from the Property dropdown

Look familiar?
Example: USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CBB&MI_01

Copy and paste these into the appropriate place:

```
;SynchroDigital INOSOP10-4.0 RES
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CBB&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0CBB&REV_0228&MI_01
```

**NOTE** I don't *think* that it matters where you paste these hardware IDs, I *think* that the variable names are just for cosmetic purposes.  I could be wrong, I don't write windows drivers.

Now copy and paste that entire entry into the [Google.NTamd64] section.  All done, try and update the driver and see whether it accepts it.

Comment: Which solution did you try? 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: The third one. I don't have a Mac at home and didn't try the second one, so I can't tell if they work or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more thing to "Error 454" answer, which btw work for me. if you simply go to device manager and say "Update driver" it wont work (did not for me).

After procedure above i have executed "echo 0xYYYY >> "%USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini" command (where YYYY is four digit number from VID_0BB4. In this case it would be "echo 0x0BB4 >> "%USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini"), and then went to device manager and in update driver procedure chosed "Browse my computer for driver software" and then chosed "Let me pick from the list of device drivers on my computer". After that, click browse and choose "android_winusb.inf". It will say that driver is not digitally signed but ignore warning and continue.

After this, execute adb kill-server and then adb devices and your device should be in the list.

I have cheap Prestigio PMP3370B tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Almost worked with the Prestigio PMP5101C QUAD as well..... the drivers seemed to work but I then had to:

1. do it again, but this time in MTP mode (it was in mass storage mode the first time which meant two entries, each with different PIDs).  (This didn't fix it, but meant it was reporting as ok in Windows in MTP mode)
2. Then follow this http://blog.itfiser.cz/android-adb-with-prestigio-multipad-pmp5080cpro-and-win7/

The vendor ID to use in 2. was 0x2207

It's worth pointing out though that it if you upgrade your version of Android installed on your PC, it will nuke the entry you added in 2.

Answer (score 0):

Modified driver works like a charm on my Prestigio PMP5770D tablet, and also on friend's Coby Kyros MID7042.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not related to Synchro Digital...
But for people who (like me) were searching on how to make **PMP5101C_QUAD** drivers work and stumbled on this post: In "android_winusb.inf" I had to add:

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&REV_0222&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&MI_01

Note that if you adding those in the wrong order like i.e.:

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0011&REV_0222&MI_01

The **adb will not recognized** it as a PMP5101C_QUAD device.