# Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B USB Driver

Tags: android, usb, driver

I am trying to setup USB debuging on Prestigio Multipad. I followed this link http://blog.itfiser.cz/android-adb-with-prestigio-multipad-pmp5080cpro-and-win7/ but I can't find setting **Storage -> USB** Computer Connection (Android version 4.0.3).

When I try to update driver (under **Device Manager->Disk Drives->PMP3370B Device**) to Google driver (located **../android-sdks/extras/google/usb_driver**) it says that the driver is up to date.

I also added Vendor ID to `%user_dir%/.android/adb_usb.ini` , restart `adb`, but still no success.  How do I Anyone with similar issues?

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874348/issue-with-tablet-detection-synchro-digital/ and pay attention on my http://stackoverflow.com/a/14084990/1274951 below. Good luck.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/prestigio-multipad-usb-debuging

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer comes a bit late, but here it is what it worked for me (I have PMP7100D, Prestigio Multipad).

Follow all the steps from the link (blog) you've provided.

What you should do extra is to install the Adb Driver Installer (http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and correctly install the drivers for the Prestigio (step by step explanation found here: http://adbdriver.com/documentations/how-to-use-android-adb-driver-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8.html). After this, when you open USBDeview your tablet should be under changed name (with the same VendorID), as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

Also, make sure that your adb_usb.ini file look like this:
[image]

Lastly do the following steps:

Open command line at %android_sdk%\platform-tools\

adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb devices

The end result should be something like: [image]