# Android USB driver for vendors who don't supply them

Tags: android, driver, android-2.3-gingerbread

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers

The above link contains a list of OEM USB Drivers for many manufacturers.

The android phone I want to hook up with eclipse is running Gingerbread. The manufacturer (not the one in the above list) didn't provide any USB driver (and I confirmed it from the company's side). Has anybody found themselves in the same position and found some workaround? I think custom ROM installation will also be hard without an USB driver, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this page on setting up and using a Universal Android Debug Bridge (ADB) driver. I've found it useful in the past, but not quite as clean as using the specific OEM drivers.

https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation.  Honestly, every time I get a new device now, I don't even bother looking for drivers, I just make one.  You can follow the procedure from the answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874830/322939

Comment: +1 for suggesting this.. paul0-ts's seemed much easier and it worked like a charm for 4 devices in a row.. more power to you, thanks!